# Escape Character \b in Python(3.4.2)

Tags: python, escaping

```
>>> print('x\b')    
x   
>>> print('x\ba')    
a    
>>> print('xyz\ba')    
xya
```

why doesn't it erase the character `'x'` in first print statement?

Comment: it does. the cursor is backed up one character, but nothing is overwriting the `x` that is already on the screen. Backspace is not the same as delete.

Comment: To verify, try e.g. `print("123\b\b4")`, printing `143`

Comment: Even with `"123\b\b4"`, whether or not the `2` is *erased* is technically up to the terminal; the terminal would be free to draw a combined 2/4 instead of completely overwriting the 2, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: `\b` is more a **cursor one left** than removing the previous one.

Backspace `\b` does **not remove** the character that is placed before the `\b`: it positions the cursor one back (given that is possible, otherwise nothing is done). Now if you then write *other* characters, the **old character is overwritten**. Compare it to an old typewriter with no correction tape. Or like this [*Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) says:

> **`8`** (backspace, BS, `\b`, `^H`), used either to erase the last character printed or to **overprint it**.

Take for instance the following print statement:

```
>>> print('aaa\b\bb')
aba
```

What actually happens is (caret `^` shows the cursor positioning):

```
^

a
 ^

aa
  ^

aaa
   ^

aaa
  ^

aaa
 ^

aba
  ^
```